# Image data tag not switching on load/resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing my own starter code for images which involves getting the window size and replacing the img src with either the `data-medium` or `data-original` depending on window size. I'm also including this with waypoints so that as you scroll it fades in the images.

I have a jsFiddle set up > https://jsfiddle.net/qkguedu9/ but my issue is this – regardless of window size, it is always pulling in the `data-medium` image. I have included JS below as essentially, even with this, it shouldn't be going wrong.

```
var browser_width,
    browser_height;

//
resizeHandler = function() {
    browser_width = $(window).width();
    browser_height = $(window).height();
}

//
$.fn.loadImage = function() {   

    return this.each(function() {

        if (browser_width > 768) {
            var toLoad = $(this).data('original');
        } else {
            var toLoad = $(this).data('medium');
        }

        var $img = $(this);

        $('<img />').attr('src', toLoad).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $img.attr('src', toLoad).addClass('loaded').removeClass('loading');
        });

    });

};

//
$(document).ready(function() {

    resizeHandler();

    //
    $('.lazy').each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        $img.waypoint(function() {
            $img.loadImage();
        }, { offset: '125%' });
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue.  When the window is larger, I get the 800x600, and when smaller, the 400x300.  The images aren't actually those sizes... but it seems the right images are showing up, so maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @holl On resize? Please see below. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a caching problem. Not too sure why that's happening, it may be a race condition of some sort. If you check the window width on the if statement, it works correctly.

```
$.fn.loadImage = function() {   

return this.each(function() {

    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        var toLoad = $(this).data('original');
    } else {
        var toLoad = $(this).data('medium');
    }

    var $img = $(this);

    $('<img />').attr('src', toLoad).imagesLoaded(function() {
        $img.attr('src', toLoad).addClass('loaded').removeClass('loading');
    });

});
```

};

Here's your fiddle that now works:

https://jsfiddle.net/qkguedu9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can see it seems to work in viewing it fullscreen but it still doesn't seem to work on resize? https://jsfiddle.net/qkguedu9/5/

Comment: Oh and I think it may be race condition but unsure?

Comment: The resizeHandler function as you currently have it may not be calculating window width in time for loadImages to check it, which leads to the if statement being evaluated as "if undefined > 768". Here's a working fiddle for the resize: https://jsfiddle.net/qkguedu9/10/   It's not perfect - you should throttle the loadTheImages callback. I use _.debounce for that kind of thing but I think jQuery has an alternative.